# Pyright, report missing imports error in neovim

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim, coc.nvim

I'm getting this error, which doesn't make sense because the libraries are installed, and the correct python interpreter path is selected. I have no clue where the issue could be.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the used Python path from `:CocCommand workspace.showOutput Pyright`, looks like Pyright was using the wrong Python.

Comment: Two ways: 1. activate the Python env before you open vim, or 2. set `python.pythonPath` in your coc-settings.json

Comment: I have the same issue. Code runs fine, but I'm seeing the same Pyright errors in vim. `which python` shows the same path as `workspace.showOutput Pyright` (they both show `/usr/bin/python`).

Comment: Update: I tried adding `"python.pythonPath: "/usr/bin/python"` to my CocConfig and the errors are gone now. Seems weird because `workspace.showOutput` was already reporting the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while looking for an answer for the same problem.

In my case, I added a `pyrightconfig.json` to the root of the project that looked something like this.

```
{
  "venvPath": "/Path/that/stores/my/venvs"
  "venv": "name_of_the_venv_that_pyright_should use.
}
```