# Vim, Pyright reports missing imports errors

Tags: vim, python-venv, pyright

I am having an error of missing imports while using Vim with coc-pyright while the code works perfectly.

[image: Import Error Image]

I am using Vim, coc-nvim with coc-pyright and venv.

```
.
├── README.md
├── data_model_venv
├── env.sample
├── pyrightconfig.json
└── src
```

I tried many solutions, including those in this post : [Pyright, report missing imports error in neovim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583492/pyright-report-missing-imports-error-in-neovim)

And thus I created the `pyrightconfig.json` :

```
{
        "exclude": [ ".venv" ],
        "venvPath": "/path/to/root/folder/data_model/",
        "venv": "data_model_venv"
}
```

`:CocCommand workspace.showOutput Pyright` gives me :

```
Workspace: /path/to/root/folder
Using python from: /path/to/root/folder/data_model_venv/bin/python

[Info  - 13:56:00.795] Pyright language server 1.1.351 starting
[Info  - 13:56:00.795] Server root directory: file:///home/myname/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-pyright/node_modules/pyright/dist
[Info  - 13:56:00.797] Starting service instance "data_model"
[Info  - 13:56:00.809] Setting pythonPath for service "data_model": "/path/to/root/folder/data_model_venv/bin/python"
[Info  - 13:56:00.809] Loading configuration file at /path/to/root/folder/data_model/pyrightconfig.json
[Info  - 13:56:00.827] Assuming Python version 3.10
[Info  - 13:56:00.827] No include entries specified; assuming /path/to/root/folder/data_model
[Info  - 13:56:01.199] Found XX source files
```

I have no clue where the error might comes from.

Comment: Does it work if you run pyright from the command line?

Comment: Yes it does, without any problem